# how do I add voices to compound species lines?

Tags: harmony, intervals, counterpoint, species-counterpoint

Update, TLDR:  given multiple semi-written lines of music, which line should be deemed the cantus firmus before working on the counterpoint of the other lines?

Given a "free" (?) soprano line (by this I mean not of any consistent rhythmic form, such as just half notes or just whole notes, etc) and a bass line in first species (whole notes only)--I believe, relative to one another, these linear structures would be called *unaligned* and *not parallel*--how should I go about filling in the alto and tenor voices using species counterpoint?  I would like for the for the lines to be "two-against-one" with the bass line (second species)?  I eventually want to include suspensions (fourth species), but i'll let that go for now.

Should my point of reference be the bass line or the soprano line?  Do I need to simplify/reduce the soprano line so that it is easier to see/build intervals?  Essentially, I would like to know the most logical way to develop my piece give a free-flowing melody and a bass line in first species.

For reference, here is the music as is:

[image]

Comment: As written, this question doesn't really make sense. Species counterpoint isn't defined by individual lines — an entire line in whole notes does not make it first species. It's defined by the relationships between the parts and the types of movements allowed. It also relies on a cantus firmus, by which the other voices are determined. But OP doesn't have a cantus firmus (or, not one that adheres to the rules of species counterpoint).

Comment: @Aaron How can I improve my question so that it makes more sense?

Comment: Short of making any changes yet, can you give me a sense of your overall goal and why you are looking to use species counterpoint?

Comment: Is this a particular exercise from the Westergaard book?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis It is not--the melody is my own.  I am just trying to accompany it with interesting alto, tenor and bass lines.

Comment: @Aaron the goal is to accompany my melody with other melodies in the other voices according to the restrictions of species counterpoint.  At a basic level, I want to develop my composition with more than just the basic triads.  I want to create a proper bach-style sound

Comment: I could, of course, dive right in and start writing lines, but I am wondering if there is a systematic approach to this.  The examples in the Westergaard book typically only deal with creating higher species in a voice after a a uniform set-up in the lower species has been created.  He starts with the skeleton and expands it from there.

Comment: @286642, have you already done all the exercises the book has for species counterpoint?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I like the way you think.  I should have, but there aren't answer keys.  I am hesitant to put in the work if I can't check myself.

Comment: @286642 Try working through Fux. He writes out the exercises, solutions, and corrections to the solutions.

Comment: Just stumbled onto an online app for learning Westergaarding species counterpoint: https://hdw.wustl.edu/westergaardian-species-counterpoint-online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you want two-against-one with the bass, it would make the most sense to use the bass as the cantus firmus. While you develop those voices, treat the soprano as a descant voice,<sup>1</sup> which will help you keep everything in sync.

I do think it would be helpful to simplify the soprano so that notes fall (primarily) on the beat, then returning them to anticipations/suspensions once the other parts are in place.

You can have it both ways by simplifying the soprano for the purpose of interval-checking as you develop the inner parts, but then play it as written for evaluating the actual composition.

---

<sup>1</sup> "Descant: an independent treble melody usually sung or played above a basic melody." (From [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20descant))